# When calculating a percentage, how to prevent going past 99% to 100%

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following to calculate a percentage:

```
var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
```

How can I keep this from going to 100%? I want to max out at 99%?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "max out"? Is this a rounding issue, or do you just not want to ever show 100%?

Comment: Make sure `data.loaded` is always strictly less than `data.total`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply by 99 instead of 100:

```
var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 99, 10)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's intended, but that will not return the correct percentage in any case. The solution provided in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8706429/1090079) will at least return the correct percentage 99% of the time.

Comment: @refp - It is intended. The question appears to disregard 100% accuracy.

Comment: @Oded I don't see that being expressed in the question, though if it satisfies OP, it satisfies OP. **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to return the value, or `99` if the value is larger than your threshold you can use `Math.min`;

```
var progress = Math.min (parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10), 99);
```

**Documentation**

- [**developer.mozilla.org - Math.min**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [<strike>**w3schools.com - JavaScript min() Method**</strike>](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_min.asp)

Comment: @Oded in this perticular case Math.min is explained in a correct manner, though I'll add another documentational link.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 99 instead, so that it ranges from 0 to 99.

Don't use parseInt for rounding, use the `round` method.

```
var progress = Math.round(data.loaded / data.total * 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for parseInt, the result of division is always a number (provided the input values don't cause an error).

If an exact value isn't necessary, the following will truncate the number to the integer part and never reach 100:

```
var progress = data.loaded / data.total * 99 | 0;
```

or if you want it a bit more precise:

```
var progress = (data.loaded / data.total * 100 | 0) % 100 || 99;
```

or precise:

```
var progress = Math.round(data.loaded / data.total * 100 ) % 100 || 99;
```